# Retrieving data from template using the foreign key of related tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to retrieve data from template level which is connected with foreign key to the derived class. But it is not working.

**Models:**

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 256)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='students', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

**Views:**

```
class SchoolListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'schools'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/School_list.html'


class SchoolDetailView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = models.School
    template_name = "basic_app/School_dtl.html"
```

**Template**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome to School Detail page</h1>
    <h2>School Details:</h2>
    <p>Name: {{ school_detail.name}} </p>
    <p>Principal: {{ school_detail.principal}} </p>
    <p>Location: {{ school_detail.location}} </p>

    <h3> Students:</h3>
    {% for student in school_detail.students.all %}
        <p>{{ student.name }} who is {{ student.age }} years old.</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I retrieve the student data from the student table from the template?

Comment: You have repeated the SchoolListView twice in the views provided. Is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks... Edited the post.